# How to deploy Vendure (headless commerce) together with Strapi CMS on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, next.js, strapi, vercel

I'm trying to deploy a webapp to Heroku. The current stack is build out of:

1. NextJS for the frontend (deployed on Vercel)
2. Strapi CMS (deployed on Heroku)

I would love to add a webshop to the webapp and would love to use the example from Vercel/commerce (https://github.com/vercel/commerce). I have selected Vendure as my favorite headless commerce provider.

I have a problem figuring out how to deploy Vendure on Heroku-platform. Is it possible to combine both Strapi and Vendure on only one Heroku app? Can both programs work together? I would think it's possible because both can work with PostgresDB.

I've read this documentation (https://www.vendure.io/docs/developer-guide/deployment/) but this doesn't speak about Heroku and the combination with Strapi.

I know my way with NextJS / Javascript / HTML, but my knowledge of the backend and deployment is not as good.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Greetings,
Bruno

Comment: one doubt, why do you need 2 CMS - strapi and vendure ? from what i see both seem to do the same job. is it possible to replace strapi with vendure in heroku ? My 2 cents, if you are planning to add vendure only for the purpose for webshop then i think it is not a good design - having related datas split in 2 cms.

Comment: Vendure is e-commerce software, strapi is a more generic CMS. I think they could work well together because they both expose one or more graphql APIs. I would not try share the same database, try keep them separate or at least use separate schemas. Then use Hasura (using a third database / schema) and configure the other APIs as remote schemas. You are now able to create relationships between all APIs and work with the Hasura API. A bit of upfront work, but it can be done all in code.

Comment: Also, a new alternative to Strapi I am investigating is payloadcms.com. But you might not need the additional complexity of a CMS if you could work out how to extend vendure to allow configuration of a landing page and a blog page.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look for inspiration/pointers at the [vendure/vendure-demo](https://github.com/vendure-ecommerce/vendure-demo) repo, it is deployed using dokku, which is a nice FOSS heroku-like deployment app for your VPS or Server.

If you want, you could use it's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/vendure-ecommerce/vendure-demo/blob/master/Dockerfile) for running it in heroku likewise or whatever dokcker compatible provider you might choose, just remove the -demo- parts you don't need about it.

I also have successfully deployed vendure and commerce with [CapRover](https://caprover.com/). Can recommend it a lot!
Which is like dokku but with a nicer webapp GUI/Installation. If you go the dokku route you have ledokku for a GUI too. Not so polished though.